# Yii get selected row data

Tags: php, yii, datatables

I have a table in my view made using the [Datatables](http://datatables.net/) jquery plugin. The last row of the table is a checkbox. I want to get the data from the DB of the selected record and pass it for saving in another model. I have no idea how to do that. Can someone give me some guidance?

Comment: you can easily do this with a gridview

Comment: The use of Datatables is required for the project.

Comment: you have to make a simple html table, then use that jquery selector on it

Comment: But that way I will just get the data displayed the table, I want get it from the DB where the full data about the record is saved. Would it work if I get one value of the table using a selector and then use a custom function to search for that value in the DB and get the id of the record this way?